# IE how to prevent text selection under overlay

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overlay, selection, z-index

I have popup with overlay, which should prevent text selection underneath. But in IE if I select popup text, text under overlay also become selected. How to fix it? Popup text should be selectable.

**[Here](http://content.screencast.com/users/chopvvs/folders/Jing/media/dd89452c-842e-4b46-a112-5620a79997b0/2015-07-09_1144.png)** is image of how it looks like.

Try it **[here (JSFiddle link)](https://jsfiddle.net/fypuvhqa/)**.

Here is html code:

```
<body style="margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             text-align: center;">
    <div class="topfixed" style="height: 200px;
                                 top: 0px;
                                 left: 0px;
                                 right: 0px;
                                 position: fixed;
                                 z-index: 0;
                                 background-color: red;">
        <div>Header</div>
        <div>Header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" style="margin-top: 200px;
                                position: relative;
                                z-index: 1;
                                background-color: blue;">
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" style="top: 0px;
                                bottom: 0px;
                                left: 0px;
                                right: 0px;
                                position: fixed;
                                z-index: 10;
                                background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyBpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEzNDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNSBXaW5kb3dzIiB4bXBNTTpJbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjAwMzBFQkFGOTM3MDExRTFBOUNCQ0YzQzcwMzE5Qzk3IiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjAwMzBFQkIwOTM3MDExRTFBOUNCQ0YzQzcwMzE5Qzk3Ij4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6MDAzMEVCQUQ5MzcwMTFFMUE5Q0JDRjNDNzAzMTlDOTciIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6MDAzMEVCQUU5MzcwMTFFMUE5Q0JDRjNDNzAzMTlDOTciLz4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+IDw/eHBhY2tldCBlbmQ9InIiPz5uy1cvAAAApklEQVR42uzRAQ0AAAjDsIMy/KvCBiGdhLWSTHSmtgCIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAiIgAARECACAkRAgAgIEAERECACAkRAvrcCDAD6kAEI03atVgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');">
    </div>
    <div class="popup" style="top: 0px;
                              bottom: 0px;
                              left: 0px;
                              right: 0px;
                              position: fixed;
                              z-index: 15;
                              color: white;
                              font-size: 48px;">
        <div>Popup Text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give body css style as

```
overflow:auto;
```

See  I have updated your fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jtjojgzh/

Comment: Already upvoted. It would take effect when I get 15 reputation.